# Android .properties file of library project overwritten

Tags: android, properties, settings, project

I created a library project and store my properties in a .properties file (release.properties and test.properties). I access them using a Properties object, which file I access depends on a boolean (DEBUG true/false).

However, if I create an app-project that uses my lib-project, and if for this app-project ONE property value differs from the lib, I have to copy the whole file into my app-project and change the one line that differs.

This is a bad situation. If I ever add a line to the .properties in my library project I will have to add it to all the app-projects, same for changing a line in the lib project.

The problem is that a .properties file in the app-project overwrites the WHOLE file in the lib-project, this overwrite is not line-based.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a CustomProperties class that on initialization loads TWO properties files, default.properties (from library project) and my.properties (from app project), into 2 different Properties objects.

In CustomProperties: create getters for String, int, boolean, etc. and in these methods check if my.properties contains the value, if so return this value, if not return the value from default.properties.

Depending on the debug setting (true or false) I choose if I take the debug files or live files. So I have 4 property files, 2 (debug + live) in library project, 2 (debug + live) in app project.